# Webpack Not Generating Source Maps in Production Mode Despite Configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm encountering an issue where Webpack does not generate source maps when building in production mode. Despite setting the `devtool` configuration option to `source-map`, the expected source maps are not created. I've tried using many other values for `devtool`, but none seem to change anything.

If i run `webpack` on its own, it generates a sourcemap file fine, but as soon as i run `NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production} webpack`, the sourcemap is not generated anymore.

webpack.config.ts:

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { Configuration } from "webpack";

const { compilerOptions } = require("./tsconfig.json");

const tsPaths = Object.keys(compilerOptions.paths).reduce(
  (paths, path) => Object.assign(paths, { [`${path}`]: resolve(__dirname, compilerOptions.paths[path][0]) }),
  {},
);

const webpackConfig: Configuration = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/handler.ts",
  },
  target: "node",
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: tsPaths,
  },
  output: {
    path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "[absolute-resource-path]",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
};

export default webpackConfig;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "paths": {
    "*": ["types/*.d.ts"]
  },
 "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

**What i've tried:**

- Verified the output path and made sure it points to the correct directory.
- Checked for any plugins or loaders that might interfere with source map generation.
- Ensured that Webpack's mode is set based on the NODE_ENV variable, and tried explicitly setting it to production.
- Updated webpack (to 5.90.3) and webpack cli (to 5.1.4)
- Added explicit source map configuration for ts-loader.
- Inspected the generated files for any inline or incorrectly referenced source maps.
- Ran Webpack with `--progress` to look for relevant warnings or errors but found none that pointed to the source of the issue